# Help center uncapitalized letter AND typo: "Note: deleted questions do not... so you if you..."

Tags: bug, status-completed, spelling, help-center, capitalization

Towards the bottom of the [Deleted Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions) page of the Help Center is the following sentence:

> Note: **deleted** questions do not appear in search results, so **you** if you
>   wish to later undelete a question that you've deleted you must have
>   saved the URL somewhere.

The word "deleted" should be capitalized here, because of the following grammar "rule" ([found here](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/marks/colon.htm)):

> If the introductory phrase preceding the colon is very brief and the
>   clause following the colon represents the real business of the
>   sentence, begin the clause after the colon with a capital letter:
>
> Remember: Many of the prominent families of this New England state
>   were slaveholders prior to 1850.

The word "you" is also duplicated (thanks @animuson), so the corrected sentence would be:

> Note: Deleted questions do not appear in search results, so if you
>   wish to later undelete a question that you've deleted you must have
>   saved the URL somewhere.

Comment: What about the "so you if you wish"? That bugs me a lot more than a non-capitalized letter.

Comment: grammar.ccc. **commienet** .edu??! Keep your yellow Red hands off my language, Ivan!

Comment: I mean, uh, nice find. I didn't actually think that was ungrammatical. In fact, I think I prefer the lowercase version.

Comment: [status-too-insignificant-to-care-about]

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I actually greatly prefer the capitalized letter, mainly because it signifies the beginning of a sentence, which it really is in this case.  It means that I can mentally ignore the beginning...  But hey that's just me, lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Huh. This is the first time I heard of that rule and I think it is weird, so I opted to avoid it completely and modified the beginning of that sentence (and threw the extra "you" out):

> Please note that deleted questions do not appear in search results, so if you wish to later undelete a question that you've deleted you must have saved the URL somewhere.

Comment: A shrewd, if not Solomonic, solution.